# How do you add a custom property in Vue Component with TypeScript and without TypeScript yelling?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

Please see this minimum example:

```
import Vue from 'vue';

Vue.extend({
  mounted() {
    this.something = null;
  }
});
```

[image: C]

The code above is making TypeScript yelling.

How can I solve this without putting my property to `data()` property?

Comment: The official Vue documentation covers how to use it with TypeScript: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html

Comment: Why don't you use the vue-property-decorator module?

Comment: @jacopotaba it's stage 2, not finished yet.

Comment: What? the module?

Comment: @jacopotaba the decorator syntax itself, future API may be changed.

Comment: For me works fine, and it saves a lot of time

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

Extract the function call outside, and type this to `any` type.

[image]